# Newbie: powering and controling a motor - 12v

Tags: dc-motor, control

This is my first time dabbling in the electronics world and I am currently working on a project for a friends work ute.

I currently am in the planning stage but I found the following motor will be more than adequate for the job at hand (flipping a plate 90 degrees on demand and then back to static position) the plate is about 1kg in total.

Now I have a few questions on this. I am a mechanic so my way of thinking is a little different. With this motor (link below) it is as simple as wiring in a positive and negative wire with a switch? Or will this require some sort of controller with parameters to rotate it to the desired angle and then switch polarity for the opposite rotation? Also this will be set up on a 12v vehicle so will it require an invertor or anything of the sorts?

https://www.robotgear.com.au/Product.aspx/Details/725-131-1-Metal-Gearmotor-37D-x-57L-mm-12V

Sorry for the newbie questions but im very new to this sort and am keen on learning.

Much thanks

Michael

Comment: My only problem I forgot to mention is that the compartment where the motor will sit, I am trying to keep as small as possible (width wise -under 30mm preffered)

Comment: How do you expect the motor to know what the *desired angle* is?

Answer (score 1):

Answering only electronics part:

> With this motor (link below) it is as simple as wiring in a positive
>   and negative wire with a switch?

If the motor has to stop after 90degree rotation of the plate, you should having feedback mechanism.  Feedback (depending on how much accurate the tilt has to be) can be through:

- rotary encoders
- stall current
- Reflective sensors
- angle inclination detection using another circuitry

Stepper motors can also be considered which can deliver precise rotations every time. Depends on the precision.

> rotate it to the desired angle and then switch polarity for the
>   opposite rotation?

Yes. You can look for **H bridges** which will reverse the polarity of the motor. Depending on the drive current of gear with maximum load, the available supply and space the H Bridge elements can be chosen. Also, you can go for IC solution.

> Also this will be set up on a 12v vehicle so will it require an
>   invertor

What is the supply range of the motor? Depending on the required torque and response time, the 12 V may be sufficient. Invertor is not necessary.

Also care for the back EMF protection, stall detection and protection of circuitry from the huge fast voltage spikes expected from a normal vehicle battery.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler way to achieve the 90degree movement which would be a 12 volt rotary actuator ( Several on E Bay $50 ish) or a solenoid driving a crank.